# Not able to access request payload in Spring filter when request type is www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring, spring-boot

A pretty simple use case:

```
class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream());
        // body is a always empty
    }
}
```

When I send a request with the content-type `application/json`, I get the actual payload. But when I send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I don't happen to get any data. I am assuming one of the spring filters is already consuming the data and leaving my filter down the line with nothing.

Do note that this issue is NOT related to the fact that we can read a stream only once. That part I have already figured out and I am creating another `HttpServletRequest` with a buffered input stream for other filters. The problem is that something else in Spring Boot is reading all of my data leaving me with nothing.

I just want a way to get my hands on the payload. It doesn't have to come from the `InputStream`, if spring could just give me the payload as a `byte[]`, it would serve my purpose.

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.5.

Comment: What is the reason to implement such filter?

Comment: So, I am exposing a LogEntries webhook that is triggered in the case of certain alerts. https://logentries.com/doc/webhookalert/ . However, they set an authorization token which is computed using the payload and I need access to it to compute it on my side and verify that the request is legit.

Comment: Your use case is similar to: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html more accurate look you should take carefully at line 277 of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java

Answer (score 1):

you can disable this via application.properties

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is **HiddenHttpMethodFilter** which consumes the stream.

Please try to disable the filter by adding below code and then check if it works

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```